# How can I cause an exception to be thrown when my code attempts to send an unserialized object via RMI?

Tags: java, serialization, exception, rmi

I've encountered an error on a codebase I was working with. Certain values were not being passed from one process to another. After much frustration, I narrowed down the culprit to a single RMI call. The client process would make a call to retrieve some data from the server. The method returns an `ArrayList` of a certain class. Debugging showed that the server properly runs through the method, but the client never regains control. The client just hangs. Digging down, I realized that the class that the client needed does not implement `Serializable`. Changing that fixed the problem. Java version is 1.6.

```
public interface RMIServer extends Remote{
    public ArrayList<MyObject> getObjects() throws RemoteException;
}

public class MyRMIServer implements RMIServer{
    public ArrayList<MyObject> getObjects() throws RemoteException{
        //All of the following code is called
        ArrayList<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        objects.add(new MyObject());
        objects.add(new MyObject());
        objects.add(new MyObject());
        return objects;
    }
}

public class RMIClient{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RMIServer rmiServer = (RMIServer)Namespace.lookup("localhost/rmiServer");
        ArrayList<MyObject> listOfObjects = rmiServer.getObjects();
        System.out.println("This is never called");
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any way to cause the client or server to throw an exception when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there any way to cause the client or server to throw an exception when this happens?

It does throw an exception. NotSerializableException. In this case, the client will receive it wrapped in a ServerException. Your client code doesn't compile, so your claim that no exception is thrown and the client never regains control lacks credibility.

Comment: Sure you never want to deploy with bugs, but you sure do want a clean way to handle it if a bug does happen. This just seems a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want to throw an exception you can use:

```
throw new YourCustomException();
```

Or you could catch the exception with a try catch if necessary but of course you should only do this to handle exceptions that you know about like a user which enters wrong data and you want to tell the user that it is wrong if this happens.

But make sure that the bugs you can fix are fixed like serializing the objects that should be serialized. These are the objects that are transported over the network.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I wanted a way to throw an exception when a particular near-undetectable exception happens.

Comment: Well, you say it is near-undetectable so their is a way to know when the exceptions happens. At this time you have to throw your own exception or catch this exception you are talking about.